# System.Drawing.Color in Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

Greetings,

I have a class (let's call it Car) that has a property of type System.Drawing.Color (Call it CarColor).  I have a script service function that uses this Car class as a return value, which works just fine.  I then have another script service function that takes a Car object as a parameter.  I would like to change the color of the car in Javascript, but I am finding it difficult to do so without adding another parameter that takes in the color as a string and is then translated at the server.

Are there any ideas on how to set the Color property of the Car object in Javascript and maintain it through to the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sharing Values Between JavaScript and C#](http://iridescence.no/post/Sharing-Variables-Between-JavaScript-and-C.aspx)